# AJAX response not rendering in JavaScript template

Tags: javascript, django, mustache

I have the following jQuery AJAX request, that returns the correct JSON response, as expected (which is a youtube ID). However, when I try to insert `ytid` into `framecode` using:

```
rendered = Mustache.render(framecode, {ytid: ytid});
```

I am left with an empty space where `{{ytid}}` should be replaced with the contents of `ytid`. 
In the firefox debugger, `ytid` shows as a string as expected, and when I run the above line in the debugger, `{{ytid}}` is replaced with the youtube id as expected. Very strange. Also, when I print `ytid` to console, it also prints correctly, so I'm sure the variable is not empty.

```
$(document).on("click", ".movlist_youtubebutton", function() {
    console.log("Youtube Button Clicked");
    var ytid = $(this).data('ytid');
    var movid = $(this).data('movid');

    function isEmpty(str) {
        return (!str || 0 === str.length);
    }

    if (isEmpty(ytid)) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/gettrailer/",
            method: "GET",
            data: {movid: movid},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                    ytid = result.ytid;
                    window.ytid = ytid;
                    console.log(ytid);
            }
        });
    }
    framecode = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ytid}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    rendered = Mustache.render(framecode, {ytid: ytid});
    console.log(rendered);
    // window.ytid = 'test3'
    console.log(ytid);
    popup = $('#popup' + movid);
    popup.popup({
        opacity: 0.3,
        transition: 'all 0.3s'
    });
    popup.popup('show');
    popup.html(rendered);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because the `$.ajax` call is async, so it's completing after `framecode` has already been assigned. You'll need to wrap the remainder of the code there in a `.then` after the `$.ajax` to fix this.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I'll post the code if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working edited code in response to Stephen's answer

```
function isEmpty(str) {
    return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}

function framereplace(ytid, movid) {
    framecode = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ytid}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    rendered = Mustache.render(framecode, {ytid: ytid});
    popup = $('#popup' + movid);
    popup.popup({
        opacity: 0.3,
        transition: 'all 0.3s'
    });
    popup.popup('show');
    popup.html(rendered);
}

$(document).on("click", ".movlist_youtubebutton", function() {
    console.log("Youtube Button Clicked");
    var ytid = $(this).data('ytid');
    var movid = $(this).data('movid');

    if (isEmpty(ytid)) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/gettrailer/",
            method: "GET",
            data: {movid: movid},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                ytid = result.ytid;
            }
        }).then(framereplace(ytid, movid)); // needs to happen after
    } else {
        framereplace(ytid, movid);
    }
});
```